# Lambda invocations problem with PutObject from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, devops, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I have created a Lambda function which trigger whenever there is PutObject event in S3 bucket. However, for example out of 1 million requests of S3 PutObject event only 500k times the lambda invocations happen. Ideally it should invoke exactly 1 million times.
How can we troubleshoot the issue?
We tried CloudTrail and Cloud watch to check logs but no luck.

Note: At present, concurrency is set to 30

Screenshot which shown sharp decline in the graph.

[image: Lambda cloud watch graph]

Comment: I wonder whether _multiple_ records might be sent to the AWS Lambda function in one invocation? Is your Lambda function looping through the Records array, or at least logging the length of that array to check whether there are more messages?

Comment: Please try to avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood.